# Gerrit reads tab, using space in Vim

Tags: git, vim, tabs, spaces

I am using a Vim to edit code and am using spaces, however when I commit and push my changes to Gerrit, it is seeing a tab. In .vimrc, I have:

```
set autoindent 
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did the tabs exist before you changed your `vimrc`? If so you can use `:retab` to apply those settings.

Comment: I think so yes, I believe I initially used a tab in vim and pushed that. So that is where the tab originates. Then I went and edited the file and .vimrc, but when I commit amend and repush the tab is still there

Comment: Hmmm...Is the tab the only thing you edited? Have you checked to make sure your changes to this file are being pushed?

Comment: Is it a makefile?

Comment: It's a .sh script

Comment: @ShaneReilly yes all other changes are visible

Comment: Use vim's `:set list` and `:set nolist` to make the existing tabs visible (and then invisible again). The `expandtab` option only expands tabs in new or re-adjusted lines. There are other ways to make vim display the tabs visually, if you prefer, but setting `list` is easy.

Comment: do you need to re "git add" the files when doing a "git commit --amend"? Maybe that's the problem

Comment: Yes, `git commit --amend` simply re-commits whatever is in Git's index. If you have not copied new data to Git's index, that re-commits the old data.